# minLength 3 on autocomplete and a button to manually search with minLength 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an autocomplete functionality where the search is not triggered when less than 3 characters are typed because of the size of the result set. However there are some names that actually only have 1 or 2 letters in their first and last name.

The solution is to allow the user to click the magnifying glass within the input to submit, or 'force through' a query with a 1 or 2 character value.

Here's where I'm at:
HTML:

```
<input id="mainSearch" class="ui-front" name="mainSearch" type="text" data-role="autocomplete" placeholder="Recognize a UPSer">
<a href="#" class="bgbutton"></a>
```

jquery:

```
$('#mainSearch').autocomplete({
    appendTo: ".inputWrapper",
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var customer = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "//database//EmployeeDirectory/",
            data: { "filterText": request.term },
            error: function (data) { console.log('Error!'); },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                    customer[i] = {
                        label: data[i].FullName,
                        Id: data[i].UserID
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        response(customer);
    }
});

$('.bgbutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('option', 'minLength', 0);
    $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('search', '');
});
```

The this works upon first try. But once 2 characters are entered clicking the submit button minLength is then set to 0 for all autocomplete functions. And backspacing to one character will make a full query.

How can both Autocomplete functions have independent minLengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code it's difficult to tell for sure.  But what happens if you immediately reset the minLength to 3 at the end of your button click event?

```
$('.bgbutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('option', 'minLength', 0);
    $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('search', '');
    $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('option', 'minLength', 3);
});
```

Comment: Nice thinking, I had tried the exact same thing. It actually disallowed the button to work. Just tried it again and it worked!!! Thanks~!

Comment: Maybe set it back to 3 when you get the Ajax success

Comment: Strange issue now is that a 2 character search is giving non-matching results.

Comment: So I checked to make sure DB queries where correct and they are not receiving data: { "filterText": request.term } on button press only on the autocomplete typing...

Comment: Turns out $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('search', ''); needed to have the field value. $('#mainSearch').autocomplete('search', $('#mainSearch').val());